# ZEND .htaccess, redirecting to www and index.php

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, redirect

this is my problem:

**Goal:**

redirect all non-www queries to www (permanent redirection if possible), AND also all queries to index.php (for proper work of Zend framework)

**Issue:**

.htaccess not working as I would like it to work

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule !^www\.(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.index.php ./ [NC,L]

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect to www try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.co\.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

To map all queries to index.php try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Here's more information about what the R, QSA & L are used for:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule